# How can i loop in python until what i want is achieved

Tags: python, loops, python-requests

I am trying to loop a request to a gaming website so i know when the latest patch notes is available. However i do not know how to loop this code so it checks every minute or every 30 seconds to see if it has changed.

```
import requests

url = "Gamewebsite.com"


print("PN is live" if len(requests.get(url).text) > 9900 else "PN not available")
```

It sends the message `PN is not available`if the website did not post the patch notes and if the website did post the patch-notes it sends `PN is live`. but i have to run it manually every time for it to work.

i want it to break after it sends `PN is live` how can i do this. any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I think you're looking for a `while loop`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try a while loop. So while condition not true print PN is not live. Then when the condition is true it will break the loop. Then after the loop add the print statement PN is Live.

Comment: Thank you i am kind of new to python as a whole but since i know if condition better than while loop your comment clicked and it works. thanks

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you can try something like this

```
while True:
   //Make your call
   if len(requests.get(url).text) > 9900:
      break

   sleep(30)
```